# Proving probability inequality (how to return to Chebychev?)

Tags: probability, inequality

Supposing $X$ is a random variable, $X>0$, $E[X^2]<+\infty$, $\lambda \in (0,1)$, I have to prove the following inequality.

$$P[X>\lambda E[X]] \geq (1-\lambda)^2 \frac{E[X]^2}{E[X^2]}$$

once shown I have to deduce that if $P[X\leq u] \leq c$, for a certain $u>0$ and $c\geq 0$ and $\forall r > 0$

$$E[X^r]\leq \frac{u^r}{1-(cE[X^{2r})^{1/2}/E[X^r]}$$

where the denominator is well defined and strictly positive.

On the first part I tried to substitute $X$ with $1/Y$ and applying the jensen's inequality to all terms but I can't find anything bigger than $E[1/Y^2]$, here is where I stopped.

$$P\left[Y<\frac{E[Y]}{\lambda}\right]\geq \frac{(1-\lambda)^2}{E^2[Y]E[1/Y^2]}.$$